# Braintree Drop-in UI - disable adding new payment method

Tags: braintree

Is there a way to disable the default behavior of automatically adding any newly-entered payment methods to the Vault record, when using Drop-in UI on web?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact 
[support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

Passing a [customer_id](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/client-token/generate/customer_id) into the [client token generation](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/client-token/generate/) will always automatically add a newly-entered credit card to the customer in your Vault.

You can always remove the customer_id from the client token generation, but you would lose the ability to have a customer choose from previously stored payment options.

You can always open a feature request [at this link](https://github.com/braintree/braintree-web-drop-in/issues).  Be sure to provide your use case, too!

Comment: I've created an issue here https://github.com/braintree/braintree-web-drop-in/issues/470

Answer (score 0):

I think this is quite late but it might be helpful for someone. Yes, you can change the existing behavior by adding below code

```
card:{ vault: { vaultCard: true, allowVaultCardOverride:true } }
```

Into your create drop-in code.